# SimpleXml support enabled but got "Call to undefined method"

Tags: undefined, simplexml

I run PHP 5.4.16 on centos 7. I've checked that SimpleXML is enabled

```
SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: 692516840b2d7d6e7aedb0bedded1f53b764a99f $
Schema support => enabled
```

but the simple

```
$xmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement('<books><book>PHP Basics</book><book>XML Basics</book></books>');
$xmlElement->rewind();
```

gives

```
Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::rewind()
```

What I'm missing ?? Note that $xmlElement->saveXML() works and when using the class SimpleXmlIterator, I can use the rewind method with no issue.

Comment: From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.rewind.php): "Prior to PHP 8.0, SimpleXMLElement::rewind() was only declared on the subclass SimpleXMLIterator." When using a PHP version which [was released more than 11 years ago](https://www.php.net/releases/#5.4.0), and [has been unsupported by the official project for nearly 8 years](https://www.php.net/eol.php), you should expect a lot of functionality to be missing.

Comment: (Possibly you actually meant PHP **7.4** not **5.4**, which would be significantly less old, but still old enough to be out of official support, and old enough that you should check the manual for when things were added.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Reading in detail the manual, as you encourage me, simpleXmlElement has some methods like rewind only since php8. As was confused with the fact that others methods I was using were common since php5.